# Crash due to missing nine patch when the nine patch is present

Tags: android, android-resources

I consistently get Crashlytics reports regarding a crash while inflating a TextView:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity 
{co.tinode.tindroidx/co.tinode.tindroid.MessageActivity}: 
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10 in 
    co.tinode.tindroidx:layout/fragment_invalid_topic: Binary XML file line #10 in 
    co.tinode.tindroidx:layout/fragment_invalid_topic: Error inflating class TextView

...

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
   Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f080067
```

This is the definition of the `TextView` which fails to inflate. The `ID #0x7f080067` is the ID of the `@drawable/bubble` nine patch.

```xml
    <TextView
        style="@style/textPrimary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/topic_not_found_or_invalid" />
```

But the `@drawable/bubble` nine-patch is present in 5 resolutions:

[image]

The only resolution that's missing is `ldpi`. That's not the resolution of the devices where it crashes though. For example, the latest crash was on `Redmi Note 7` (API 29) which is not an `ldpi` device. The other recent crashes were on `OPPO A9` (API 28) and `Sony Xperia Z5 Premium` (API 25).

The other resources are also present:

The `@string/topic_not_found_or_invalid` is present in all translations. Even if it were missing in one of the translation it would fall back to English.

The style is there too:

```xml
    <style name="textPrimary" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

And the color `@color/colorTextPrimary`:

```xml
    <color name="colorTextPrimary">#212121</color>
```

I cannot reproduce the crash on any of my devices or in an emulator. I'm completely baffled. What could be the reason for the crash?

Comment: Hi Gene! Did you remove "9" from name of drawable image and tried?

Comment: Any updates?...

Comment: Nope. The crashes slowly stopped. Maybe Google has patched the bug. Or maybe users with buggy Android stopped using the app. It seems to be an Android bug though.

Comment: It's probably related to this bug https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1285